# All controls on a form are invisible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've run into a bizarre problem. Given only this code (that I've cut down to the bare essentials), the form will appear but all controls on it are invisible, even though their individual `Visible` properties are true:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new WaveformWindow());
    }
}

// ...

public partial class WaveformWindow : Form
{
    public WaveformWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

// ...

partial class WaveformWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 27);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        // 
        // WaveformWindow
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(398, 373);
        this.Name = "WaveformWindow";
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Text = "WaveformWindow";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

Comparing between working and broken versions of the non-stripped program, the only file that changed is the form designer file.

Comment: Most GUI toolkits I've used require that you add your widgets to the window/canvas after creating them. Does winforms automatically find labels among the `private` members of a class and show them? Or must they also be added to the window/canvas somehow?

Comment: Along the lines of code you have shown i can't see label being added to Form's control collection.. that means label is NOT even on the form.. its just declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the controls to the form to make them visible. 
See... **this.Controls.Add(this.label1);** below

```
        // 
        // WaveformWindow
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(398, 373);
        this.Name = "WaveformWindow";
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Text = "WaveformWindow";
      **this.Controls.Add(this.label1);**
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Windows forms generates the code to add all the controls to forms automatically. So whenever u face such problem, delete the old control and again drag and drop it. It must be then visible.  (Edit for understanding the issue)

Comment: we know that line should be there.. but that should automatically be done by designer... you can't be sure designer kept your changed code.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: Yes thats true, designer must do it automatically. But I think he might have tried to append the designer code. Because this has never been reported as problem of Windows Designer Code Generation

Comment: thats what i am saying.. the usual remedy would be to delete the code (in designer code ) of label and add a new label again on the form (in Designer not ode)

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: Completely agree.

Comment: I never modified the designer code. That's strange that the designer failed to add the control.

Comment: @Reinderien: Yes its strange.. but I think it wouldn't be a permanent problem. Once in a year you may face this kinda problem. Its when designer gets confused about something. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this problem is semi-permanent. I'm posting a new question about it now that I know more about the problem.